# Randomly Generate 2d background

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine

I am creating a Unity 2d game and need help with where to start with creating a randomly generated background. The background is just a series of colored blocks I need the blocks to continue infinitely and change between 6 different colors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what kind of pattern you want. But I think you should look in to using perlin noise in this instance.

If you are coding in c#, there are a bunch of perlin libraries you easily can implement, such as Simplexnoise

https://code.google.com/p/simplexnoise/

This can give you a static value when you input two parameters such as X and Y. And it will always be the same when using that specific seed.